# const and static cast together

Tags: c++, casting

I have a reference to a object of child class type passed as const pointer of parent class type.
I need to cast this pointer to non-const child class.

Is there anything better than `static_cast<child*>(const_cast<parent*>(pParent))`?

Comment: may replace the `static_cast` by `dynamic_cast` in case you want have RTTI information about the cast success.

Comment: Do you have a const pointer, or a pointer-to-const?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` would be better, if `parent` is polymorphic. Better still would be to use a less crazy design. `const_cast` is a rancid code smell.

Comment: In other words, there is no simple way to do the down-const-cast in one step. You all are discussing only the RTTI check.
And yes it is a const pointer.

Comment: @V-X: Technically, you could do it in one step with an evil C-style cast. But don't. This monstrosity at least makes it clear that something monstrous is happening. `dynamic_cast`, if possible, would be slightly better (in the sense of safer) since it would at least enforce type-correctness, but not const-correctness.

Comment: @MikeSeymour "`const_cast` is a rancid code smell." not necessarily, many third-party APIs, for example, have a userdata pointer which is `void *`. As far as I am aware, you have to either then strip away the `const` with `const_cast` or allocate a temporary structure just to stuff that const pointer behind a non-const pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the passed pointer points to an object of type `child` or subobject thereof, use

```
static_cast<child const*>(pParent)
```

Note that this induces undefined behavior(!) if the above condition is not fulfilled, so if the possibility exists that the pointer doesn't point to an object of type `child`, and `parent` is polymorphic, use `dynamic_cast` with the same syntax instead. It will return a null pointer if the cast isn't valid, determining the latter through RTTI.